# Best way to structure a service in node.js/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am starting to move the logic away from the routes in the express application, into a service provider. One of these routes deals with streams, not only that, it also requires some more logic to take place once the stream is finished. Here is an example of the express route.

```
router.get("/file-service/public/download/:id", async(req, res) => {

try {

    const ID = req.params.id;

    FileProvider.publicDownload(ID, (err, {file, stream}) => {

        if (err) {

            console.log(err.message, err.exception);
            return res.status(err.code).send();

        } else {

            res.set('Content-Type', 'binary/octet-stream');
            res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + file.filename + '"');
            res.set('Content-Length', file.metadata.size);

            stream.pipe(res).on("finish", () => {

                FileProvider.removePublicOneTimeLink(file);

            });
        }
    })

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send(e);
} 

})
```

And here is one of the functions inside the service provider.

```
this.publicDownload = async(ID, cb) => {

    const bucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
        chunkSizeBytes: 1024 * 255,
    })

    let file = await conn.db.collection("fs.files")
    .findOne({"_id": ObjectID(ID)})

    if (!file|| !file.metadata.link) {

        return cb({
            message: "File Not Public/Not Found",
            code: 401,
            exception: undefined
        })

    } else {

        const password = process.env.KEY;
        const IV = file.metadata.IV.buffer

        const readStream = bucket.openDownloadStream(ObjectID(ID))

        readStream.on("error", (e) => {
            console.log("File service public download stream error", e);
        })

        const CIPHER_KEY = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password).digest()        

        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', CIPHER_KEY, IV);

        decipher.on("error", (e) => {
            console.log("File service public download decipher error", e);
        })

        cb(null, {
            file, 
            stream: readStream.pipe(decipher)
        })
    } 

}
```

Because it is not wise to pass res or req into the service provider (I'm guessing because of unit test).I have to return the stream inside the callback, from there I pipe that stream into the response, and also add an on finish event to remove a one-time download link for a file. Is there any way to move more of this logic into the service provider without passing res/req into it? Or am I going at this all wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking for help with?  It seems like you're going out of your way to not pass the response writeStream into the code (why?) that's handling the download.  By definition, that does NOT allow you to encapsulate the functionality inside your download function and forces this split personality.  Why are you refusing to pass the writestream into the download code?  That's how you simplify this.

Comment: @jfriend00 Because it seems like it bad practice to pass response into the provider, the guide I am following is this one here: https://www.qat.com/simple-rest-service-node-js-express/ As you can see he never passes res/req into the provider, and only lets the route handle the res/req.

Comment: Well, then pick your poison.  Your code has to be a lot more complicated because you aren't passing in the writestream therefore you have to split the code between code that has access to the writeStream and the code that doesn't and therefore you can't encapsulate the whole download logic in the download object.  You asked how to simplify it.  Pass in the writeStream - that's how.  These so-called "guidelines" are situational, not absolute.  You make a judgement on what makes the best code.

Comment: FYI, that article you linked to doesn't say don't ever pass `req` or `res` to other code.  And, those examples are all very simple database transactions that have no need to interact directly with `req` or `res`.  And, when it shows you how to test it, it uses a full-on rest client to test the whole server - it's not even trying to test the individual data methods.  I still don't know where you get this idea that passing the writeStream into some code whose job it is to send stuff down that writestream is a bad idea.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay I do see what you're saying, sorry for my ignorance I am still learning, but if i just passed response into the service provider, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using the service all together? I don't see how it would be different than just keeping everything in the express route. And when i create test, wouldn't I need some way to mock the express server? But if i break up the non-express logic (i.e creating users in mongoDB, ect.), I can test just that logic without having to mock the express library?

Comment: And, FYI that code's a bit out of date because the modern implementation of `UserProvider` would have their asynchronous methods returning promises, not using plain callbacks.  Not entirely relevant to the download case, but it's not a state-of-the-art article.

Comment: You can mock a stream interface just fine to unit test things - it's a standard interface.  Right now, you can't really unit test it at all without all the code (or a mock of the same code) that's in the request handler.

Comment: There's still value to abstracting out all the download logic into it's own module or function, even if you pass it the response stream.  For one, if you parameterize it properly, it can be reusable in other places in your code for other downloads.  I think you're code will be significantly simpler and just as testable, perhaps even easier to test since all the relevant functionality is in one place and all you need to do mock a response write stream.  Use YOUR judgement on what makes the best code for this particular situation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay this is all making much more sense now, I see how this could over complicate things for the wrong reasons. Should I keep the res.set() out of the service provider? And treat res basically like its just a write stream inside of the service? Or should i put that into the service provider too?

Comment: It's personal opinion now, but I think setting up the appropriate headers for the download are part of the encapsulated download logic (that's where the code knows what the file type is) so it can be in the download function. Otherwise, you have to create a callback back to the request handler just to set those. Those methods are also easy to mock for testability purposes if you want to test the download function independently. Or you can test it with a real response in a test app because the request handler has now been made trivial since you just pass everything off to the download function.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was doing more research, and this github page https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices#1-project-structure-practices on the "1.2 Layer your components, keep Express within its boundaries" Section says it is bad practice to pass res/ref and its a common mistake among devs. It seems to be regularly updated, and also https://dev.to/santypk4/bulletproof-node-js-project-architecture-4epf states the same. Basically they are saying you should not mix business logic with web layer objects (req,res)

Comment: I go back to what I've said a couple times.  There are no absolute rules in this kind of stuff.  Choose what makes the simple, most maintainable code also with an eye for how you would test it.  These type of guidelines are something to consider, but NOT something to make a mess because of.  Downloading a file IS all about the response stream.  That's what it does.  IMO, it's a waste to abstract the writestream just because of a guideline suggestion and make much, much more complicated code.  But, you make your own decision on that.

Comment: Ask yourself how you would unit test what you have now?  You have split half the code in two places, neither of which can be independently tested.  Is that really a good thing?  I don't think so.  I'd argue you should also not put half the implementation in the request handler and half in the service either.  FYI, downloading a file is not business logic.  It's web logic.  Getting the filename might be business logic, but downloading it is web logic.  So, I don't think that demarcation particularly applies here - at least not how you've structured your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't understand how I wouldn't be able to unit test with code like this, for the file download I could make sure a read stream was returned (Also the file object itself). And why wouldn't I also be able to still mock express and make sure express returns the right data? The "Bulletproof" link i provided, tests the service provider in his example, but why couldn't I do both?

Comment: I've made my points.  Not really supposed to have a long discussion here in comments.

Comment: @jfriend00 Alright thank you for you feedback I appreciate it

Comment: Also, note that you are missing a bunch of error handling which also requires communication back to the express code and the response object.  For example, if `readStream.on("error", ...`) or `decipher.on("error", ...)` triggers, you have no error handling.  If the response stream gets an error, you don't even catch that and you have to do something different if the response has already started flowing vs. not started yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to move more of this logic into the service provider without passing res/req into it?

As we've discussed in comments, you have a download operation that is part business logic and part web logic.  Because you're streaming the response with custom headers, it's not as simple as "business logic get me the data and I'll manage the response completely on my own" like many classic database operations are.

If you are going to keep them completely separate while letting the download process encapsulate as much as it can, you would have to create a higher bandwidth interface between your service provider and the Express code that knows about the `res` object than just the one callback you have now.

Right now, you only have one operation supported and that's to pass the piped stream.  But, the download code really wants to specify the content-type and size information (that's where it's known inside the download code) and it wants to know when the write stream is done so it can do its cleanup logic.  And, something you don't show is proper error handling if there's an error while streaming the data to the client (with proper cleanup in that case too).

If you want to move more code into the downloader, you'd have to essentially make a little interface that allows the service code to drive more than one operation on the response, but without having an actual response object.  That interface doesn't have to be a full response stream.  It could just have methods on it for getting notified when the stream is done, starting the streaming, setting headers, etc...

As I've said in the comments, you will have to decide if that actually makes the code simpler or not.  Design guidelines are not absolute.  They are things to consider when making design choices.  They shouldn't drive you in a direction that gives you code that is significantly more complicated than if made different design choices.